# Why mmap a 4GB file on 32-bit armv7l succeeded?

Tags: c++, memory, mmap

I had the impression from the `mmap(2)` man page and search results, that `mmap` is only limited to system's available address spaces, minus the system reserved address spaces. So on 32-bit armv7l, I assume it's around 3GB = (4GB - 1GB).

But it seemed like I could actually `mmap` a 5 GB file without any problem:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        // stats
        char * path = argv[1];
        struct stat sb; 
        stat(path, &sb);
        std::cout << "File size: " << sb.st_size << std::endl;  

        // open
        int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY, S_IRWXU);
        std::cout << "File descriptor: " << fd << std::endl;
        int i;
        for (i =0; i<10; ++i){
                void *pa = mmap(
                        nullptr, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
                std::cout << "PA: " << pa  
                        << ", MAP_FAILED: " 
                        << (pa == MAP_FAILED) << ", Status: " 
                        << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        }   
}
```

Compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag:

```
g++  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 test.cc
```

And the result yields:

```
File size: 5045966585
File descriptor: 3
PA: 0x89f80000, MAP_FAILED: 0, Status: Success
PA: 0x5d34a000, MAP_FAILED: 0, Status: Success
PA: 0x30714000, MAP_FAILED: 0, Status: Success
PA: 0x3ade000, MAP_FAILED: 0, Status: Success
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
PA: 0xffffffff, MAP_FAILED: 1, Status: Cannot allocate memory
```

From the results, mmap succeeded for 4 times before going into real troubles. But it shouldn't have been succeeded since the file is ~5GB.

My questions would be:

1. Is this behavior expected for `mmap`?
2. If not, where did I do wrong?

---

Edit:

> With physical addres extension (PAE) 32-bit systems can addres much more than 2^32 bytes, if that is available.

There's no PAE support for this CPU

```
$> cat /proc/cpuinfo

Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 1436.46

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 1436.46

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : sun7i
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 09c11b9d52544848804857831651664b
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question and just FYI, but when printing a pointer using the `printf` format `"%p"` the argument *should* be a `void *`, so no casting needed. Also there is an [output operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking a `void *` used to print pointers, so no need for the old C `printf` function at all.

Comment: With physical addres extension (PAE) 32-bit systems can addres much more than 2^32 bytes, if that is available.

Comment: What is the function prototype for `mmap()`?  If the second argument is only 32 bits, your 64-bit `sb.st_size` may be getting truncated.

Comment: Yup, the overflow causes only 716 MB to be allocated.

Comment: Are you aware that the difference between 1GB and 1GiB is not as negligible as is the difference between 1kB and 1kiB?

Comment: @hetepeperfan in ARM it's LPAE. But that's how the OS can recognize the memory. Each process' address space is still limited to 32-bit pointer, hence 2-4GB of RAM

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed, the `sizeof(size_t)` is 4 and the `sizeof(off_t)` is 8 if I compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. Without that flag, it's 4.

Comment: @c3V6a2Vy, the second parameter is a `size_t`. The *last* parameter of `mmap` is an `off_t`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PAE is irrelevant. This is not about accessing large amounts of physical memory.

The problem is that your `mmap` function takes a 32-bit value for the size of the mapping. So your 64-bit size gets truncated and you're actually allocating less than 1 GB of virtual memory.