# What is iOS app's address space?

Tags: ios, memory-address, segmentation-fault

TL;DR: Is there a way to find out what range of addresses are valid for my app running in the Debugger? Alternatively a call (c `stdlib` or Cocoa) that would confirm or deny the validity of an address.

(The address values I am referring to are from the app's POV, i.e. before VM translation.)

I am getting an (intermittent, of course) `ENV_BAD_ACCESS` failure when dereferencing a pointer returned by `mmap()`. (This is 3rd-party code.)

The returned value isn't `MAP_FAILED` aka -1. `Errno` is not being set.

I can't tell by inspection if the addresses are bad, although typical values (e.g. `0x23F27000`) don't look like the addresses I expect to see (e.g. `0x70000xxxxxxx`). However, good `mmap()` addresses and bad ones look alike in this regard. Anyway, I haven't been very in touch with hardware since the 6502 chip. Gone like the dodo. (The chip, not me!)

Comment: If I were in your position, I'd try enabling zombie objects first and see if the debugger might be able to give you details regarding the selector that caused the crash.

Comment: It's not a selector. Mmap() is a low-level C function and the crash is occurring in third-party video decompression C code.

Comment: Perhaps the mmap returned address gets truncated along the way like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420487/5329717 . Is the lib 32 or 64bit?